# Unable to install latest version of package from npm

Tags: node.js, npm, package, version

I have a personal package on npm here https://www.npmjs.com/package/dashfleet-firebase-path-fns

The latest version is `1.5.23`. However, `npm i dashfleet-firebase-path-fns@latest` only installs `1.5.21`. Even if I do `npm i dashfleet-firebase-path-fns@1.5.23`, I can't install `1.5.23` and get a warning that it's not in the available packages.

I'm not sure how to debug this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have a correct version in package.json and that you're not caching the requests to the npm registry.

You may try to remove the locally (and globally) installed modules and purge your cache. Also make sure you're not using a proxy or private registry.

Comment: yeah running `npm cache clean` fixes the issue!